# cannot load key using phpseclib

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssh, sftp, phpseclib

Need help. Im using  phpseclib 0.3.10 and i think i cannot load my privatekey. 
This is my code.

```
                include('Net/SFTP.php');
                include('Crypt/RSA.php');

                $sftp = new Net_SFTP('mydomin.net');
                $key = new Crypt_RSA();
                $key->setPassword('anypass');
                $key->loadKey(file_get_contents(FCPATH.'path/to/id_rsa'));
                if (!$sftp->login('username', $key) && !$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
                    exit('Login Failed');
                }

                print_r($sftp->nlist());
```

It return login failed. I can connect to the remote in filezilla using that private key. I already search anywhere in google but the result still the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (!$sftp->login('username', $key) && !$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }
```

You're trying to login with an RSA key and then a password. Unless you're server really is utilizing multi-factor authentication then you probably just want to do `!$sftp->login('username', $key)` and not the `!$sftp->login('username', 'password')` bit.

My guess: you're only doing the password bit with Net_SSH2 because your RSA private key is password protected.